# Humanoid robot with Raspberry pi

Tags: robotic-arm

I am in the midst of designing a humanoid robot, and I am very new at this technical stuff, but I have found servo motors which are capable of producing 500 kg.cm.

Now I am looking at making a raspberry pi cluster for controlling the robot, running different python scripts on each cluster node.
I imagine one raspberry pi dedicated to getting a depth map by use of webcams, and another raspberry pi downloading the frames and recognizing objects in the frames, and then both raspberry pis creating a 3D map of the environment..
But how do I go about making a wireless cluster of raspberry pis which run node specific individual codes?

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics*, L. Lars. You seem to have the project structured - you're going to use a raspberry pi for each task. It's not clear what else you're looking for. If you want to figure out how to connect them all on a wireless network, just use a wireless router. If you are trying to figure out how to get each pi to act like a node, consider a framework like [ROS](http://www.ros.org).

Comment: You're describing a very large project that will take a very long amount of time to complete; I would suggest just starting the project and coming back with the *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*. Questions which ask for a list of approaches or a subjective recommendation on a method (for how to build something, how to accomplish something, what something is capable of, etc.) are off-topic. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works.

Answer (score 2):

I don't say this negatively, but - that's a mouthful. I recommend subdividing the problem into smaller tasks that you can simulate first, to help you get a sense of the magnitude of what you're trying to do. Clustering RPis is one of the smallest problems on that list.

To answer your direct question, you would build networked service apps with those responsibilities, start the correct one on the correct node, and have them communicate with each other. You would need to also provide networking gear (a regular switch is easiest, maybe even gets you PoE) to link them together. You aren't really doing "clustering" in your model, you're just delegating responsibilities to different nodes.